# Serialization and generic list with dynamic element name

Tags: c#, serialization

I would like to know if it is possible to change the element name of the generic list when serializing the following class.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName= "MyFoo")]
public class Foo : List<Foo2>
{
    #region Private Members
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    #endregion
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName="YourFoo")]
public class Foo2
{
}


The output is:
<MyFoo>
  <Foo2/>
</MyFoo>

The desire output:
<MyFoo>
  <YourFoo/>
</MyFoo>
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise this behavior. Changing the class name and the xml tag being different is weird. Maybe you should change the class name to youfoo.

Comment: Can you give me specific reason as to why doing so is bad?

Comment: The xml tag should be similar with the class name. If there is another class with youfoo, then the whole thing gets mixed up. Same tag, same class name is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `XmlRoot` on `Foo2` to `XmlType` and `ElementName` to `TypeName`, like this:

```
[Serializable, XmlType(TypeName="YourFoo")]
public class Foo2
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, been looking for this for a while :-)

How do you control the element-name of the List collection e.g.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "BOOKS")]
public static List<ObjBook> BookList = new List<ObjBook>();
```

XML result:

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <Author>Auther1</Author>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <Author>Auther2</Author>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

I know you can set the XmlRootAttribute of the XmlSerializer, but I'm curious if it can be done by an attribute of the List?

*(I did consider creating a new question, but it's so close related so I thought it was OK)*